# populated cascading dropdown-lists for Contact Form 7 in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form-7, cascadingdropdown

hey guys I hope you are doing well.
I used to use this code that I copied from a website, and it worked without any problems.
but suddenly it won't work anymore.
I don't know why, can anyone help?
PS: I don't have that much experience in PHP :)

The code has 4 parts:

first: **Server-side script (PHP). Add this code to functions.php**
I added this function at the bottom of my theme’s functions.php file:

```
<?php
function ajax_cf7_populate_values() {

        // read the CSV file in the $makes_models_years array

    $makes_models_years = array();
    $uploads_folder = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'];
    $file = fopen($uploads_folder.'/make_model_year.csv', 'r');

    $firstline = true;
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
        if ($firstline) {
            $firstline = false;
            continue;
        }
        $makes_models_years[$line[0]][$line[1]][] = $line[2];

    }
    fclose($file);

        // setup the initial array that will be returned to the the client side script as a JSON object.

    $return_array = array(
            'makes' => array_keys($makes_models_years),
            'models' => array(),
            'years' => array(),
            'current_make' => false,
            'current_model' => false
        );

        // collect the posted values from the submitted form

    $make = key_exists('make', $_POST) ? $_POST['make'] : false;
    $model = key_exists('model', $_POST) ? $_POST['model'] : false;
    $year = key_exists('year', $_POST) ? $_POST['year'] : false;

        // populate the $return_array with the necessary values

    if ($make) {
        $return_array['current_make'] = $make;
        $return_array['models'] = array_keys($makes_models_years[$make]);
        if ($model) {
        $return_array['current_model'] = $model;
        $return_array['years'] = $makes_models_years[$make][$model];
        if ($year) {
                $return_array['current_year'] = $year;
            }
            }
        }

        // encode the $return_array as a JSON object and echo it
        
        echo json_encode($return_array);
        wp_die();

}

// These action hooks are needed to tell WordPress that the cf7_populate_values() function needs to be called
// if a script is POSTing the action : 'cf7_populate_values'

add_action( 'wp_ajax_cf7_populate_values', 'ajax_cf7_populate_values' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cf7_populate_values', 'ajax_cf7_populate_values' );
```

second: **Client side script (JavaScript). Add this to footer.php**
I add this code to footer.php, right before the  tag.

```
<script>
    (function($) {

        // create references to the 3 dropdown fields for later use.

        var $makes_dd = $('[name="makes"]');
        var $models_dd = $('[name="models"]');
        var $years_dd = $('[name="years"]');


        // run the populate_fields function, and additionally run it every time a value changes

        populate_fields();
        $('select').change(function() {
            populate_fields();
        });

        function populate_fields() {

            var data = {

                // action needs to match the action hook part after wp_ajax_nopriv_ and wp_ajax_ in the server side script.

                'action' : 'cf7_populate_values', 

                // pass all the currently selected values to the server side script.

                'make' : $makes_dd.val(),
                'model' : $models_dd.val(),
                'year' : $years_dd.val()
            };

            // call the server side script, and on completion, update all dropdown lists with the received values.

            $.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data, function(response) {
                all_values = response;

                $makes_dd.html('').append($('<option>').text(' -- choose make -- '));
                $models_dd.html('').append($('<option>').text(' -- choose model  -- '));
                $years_dd.html('').append($('<option>').text(' -- choose year -- '));

                $.each(all_values.makes, function() {
                    $option = $("<option>").text(this).val(this);
                    if (all_values.current_make == this) {
                        $option.attr('selected','selected');
                    }
                    $makes_dd.append($option);
                });
                $.each(all_values.models, function() {
                    $option = $("<option>").text(this).val(this);
                    if (all_values.current_model == this) {
                        $option.attr('selected','selected');
                    }
                    $models_dd.append($option);
                });
                $.each(all_values.years, function() {
                    $option = $("<option>").text(this).val(this);
                    if (all_values.current_year == this) {
                        $option.attr('selected','selected');
                    }
                    $years_dd.append($option);
                });
            },'json');
        }

    })( jQuery );
</script>
```

third: **I put the csv file in the uploads folder with this path ( public_html/wp-content/uploads) with name (make_model_year.csv)** and the file like this image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1hcW.png)

four: **I make the form in the contact 7 plugin.** like this

```
[select makes]
[select models]
[select years]
```

I tried a lot of things including:

- changing the name of the CSV file
- deleting the plugin and installing it again
- deleting the code and putting it back

but none of this worked.

Comment: I had issues Contact Forms 7 causing high CPU usage. To the point I've stopped using it and wrote this comment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You say it doesn't work, but it's not clear exactly what problem you're experiencing. What's the exact error or unexpected behaviour you experience? Please edit your question with that information.  Also, please replace the link to an image with text directly contained in this question. This page explains why that is important: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @SimonMayer
The problem is It's not show any results in the dropdowns lists
I don't know what to do
I'm not familiar with php so could you giude me of what errors should I shared ?